# Truncation of last letter in AngularJS CKEditor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have a web page which uses CKEditor to create a simple edit pane for writing messages. The issue I have is that when I click to send the message, the content that is retrieved from CKEditor is the content of the pane, but with the last letter truncated.

Below is what I believe to be the relevant code from the application:

```
appDirectives.directive('ckEditor', function() {
    return {
        require : '?ngModel',
        link : function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], {
                toolbar: [
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste' ] },
                    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] }
                ],
                removePlugins: 'elementspath'
            });

            if (!ngModel)
                return;

            ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });

            function updateModel() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            }

            ck.on('change', updateModel);
            ck.on('key', updateModel);
            ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

            ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="sendButton" ng-click="send()" type="button">
            Send
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
    {{message.content | warnIfContentMaxExceeded}}
    </div>
    <div class="body">
       <textarea ck-editor="" id="contentEditor" 
                 name="contentEditor" rows="10" cols="60" 
                 ng-model="message.content" 
                 value="message.content"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And from the controller:

```
$scope.send = function() {
    var msg = $scope.message;
    // ...
}
```

Looking at my directive for setting up the editor, I'm guessing that perhaps, the `ck.on('change', updateModel);` is not being triggered as soon as a character is written to the editor. However, clicking away from the box does not seem to trigger any kind of on-change event, so I'm not sure.

Is there an error in the configuration/code?

Or do I perhaps just need to upgrade to a newer version of CKEditor?

Using:

- AngularJS :: 1.3.4
- ng-ckeditor :: 0.2 (ckeditor 4.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that if updateModel is firing too quickly by creating a small throttle to it, I've done it a few times with scrolling stuff and with CKE events too.

Something like this untested method might work:

```
var throttle = -1;
function updateModelThrottle() {
    if (throttle != -1) {
        if (console && console.log) { console.log("Throttled!"); }
        clearTimeout(throttle);
    }
    throttle = setTimeout(updateModel, 500);
}
function updateModel() {
    if (console && console.log) { console.log("Firing!"); }
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        throttle = -1;
    });
}

ck.on('change', updateModelThrottle);
ck.on('key', updateModelThrottle);
ck.on('dataReady', updateModelThrottle);
```

Comment: If this is not the solution, I'm happy to delete this answer later.

Comment: It seems like an awfully hacky thing to do ... but it does actually work! And it works for this version of CKEditor/Angular, so I'm going to give it to you. I think I'll also create a separate answer, because I found that upgrading to CKEditor 4.4.6 also resolved the issue. So I'm guessing that there was a bug in 4.1.2, which your solution works around, for which a fix has since been written.

Comment: For me it worked to just simply wrap the `updateModel` into `setTimeout(..., 0)`. My guess would be that this is a hacky way to "jump over" CKEditor's event handlers within JS event queue

Answer (score 2):

Based on my own further investigations, I have found that upgrading to CKEditor 4.4.6 resolves the issue.

I must assume that a bug in the earlier version has been fixed at some point between 4.1.2 and 4.4.6.

**Note** - This may be the preferred solution for many. However, the answer from @Nenotlep works for this version of CKEditor, so I'm accepting that and also creating this answer for additional information.